# Rest API get call - put data in array - with typescript and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, rest

I want to write a function that gets the data from the rest api get call and then saves that data that was received in an array. Right now I can get the data to show up correctly in the console (the console.log(response) shows the correct data that is returned from the api call). But the dinos useState array is always undefined, even though it should be set to the correct data in the getData method. What can I do to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const ALL_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/products";
const SMALL_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/size/Small/products";
const MEDIUM_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/size/Medium/products";
const LARGE_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/size/Large/products";
const CARNIVORE_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/diet/Carnivore/products";
const HERBIVORE_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/diet/Herbivore/products";
const OMNIVORE_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/diet/Omnivore/products";
const ALL_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/products";
const SMALL_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/size/Small/products";
const MEDIUM_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/size/Medium/products";
const LARGE_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/size/Large/products";
const CARNIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/diet/Carnivore/products";
const HERBIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/diet/Herbivore/products";
const OMNIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/diet/Omnivore/products";



export default function AllProducts() {
var header: string = "";
var url: string = "";
var apiUrl: string = "";
const [dinos, setDinos] = useState([]); 

const handleSetDinos = (e: any) => {
  setDinos(e);
  console.log(dinos)
};

    const renderImageAndHeader = () => {
        url = window.location.href
        switch (url) {
            case ALL_DINOS: {
                header = "All Dinosaurs"
                apiUrl = ALL_DINOS_API_CALL
                return Omnivores
            }
            case SMALL_DINOS: {
                header = "Small Dinosaurs"
                apiUrl = SMALL_DINOS_API_CALL
                return Small
            }
            case MEDIUM_DINOS: {
                header = "Medium Dinosaurs"
                apiUrl = MEDIUM_DINOS_API_CALL
                return Medium
            }
            case LARGE_DINOS: {
                header = "Large Dinosaurs"
                apiUrl = LARGE_DINOS_API_CALL
                return Large
            }
            case CARNIVORE_DINOS: {
                header = "Carnivore Dinosaurs"
                apiUrl = CARNIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL
                return Carnivores
            }
            case HERBIVORE_DINOS: {
                header = "Herbivore Dinosaurs"
                apiUrl = HERBIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL
                return Herbivores
            }
            case OMNIVORE_DINOS: {
                header = "Omnivore Dinosaurs"
                apiUrl = OMNIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL
                return Omnivores
            }
        }
    }

    function getData(url: string) {
      fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok)
          return Promise.resolve ({ status:response.statusText}) && response.json() 
        else 
          return response.json()
      }
      )
      .then(response => JSON.stringify(response))
      .then(response => JSON.parse(response))
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .then((data) => {
          handleSetDinos(data)
        })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Comment: `.then(response => console.log(response))` This line is returning undefined and data becomes undefined which sets dinos to undefined. Remove this line and please try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all of the unneccessary JSON parsing and stringifying:

```
function getData(url: string) {
      fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => handleSetDinos(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```